# Blade Template PHP Logic preg_replace multi dimensions array

Tags: php, templates, multidimensional-array, preg-replace, laravel-blade

I am trying to replace {{blahblah}} in string from array. But stuck with multi dimensions array.

```
<?php
$content = "hello {{var}} world {{var2}} of what {{var3.var5}}?"; 
$data = ["var"=>"hello", "var2"=>"world", "var3"=>["var4"=>"what","var5"=>"asdf"]];
echo preg_replace(array_map(
    function ($k) {
        return "/\{\{$k}}/";
    }, array_keys($data)), array_map(function($x){
        if(is_array($x)){
            // some logic
        };
        return $x;
    },$data), $content);
?>
```

Expected output should be

```
hello hello world world of what asdf?
```

But its error, array to string conversion, I understand error but failed to build the logic.

here is another try by converting multi dimension to single array.

```
<?php
function flat_array(&$array, $key=''){
    foreach($array as $key=>$val){
        if(is_array($val)){
            flat_array($val);
            foreach($val as $k=>$v){
                $array["{$key}_$k"] = $v;
            }
            unset($val);
        }
    }
}
$content = "hello {{var}} world {{var2}} of what {{var3_var5}}?";
$data = ["var"=>"hello", "var2"=>"world", "var3"=>["var4"=>"what","var5"=>"asdf","var6"=>["last"=>"world"]]];
echo __FILE__.":".__LINE__.'<hr><pre>';print_r($data);echo'</pre>';
flat_array($data);
echo __FILE__.":".__LINE__.'<hr><pre>';print_r($data);echo'</pre>';
echo preg_replace(array_map(function ($k) {return "/\{\{$k}}/";}, array_keys($data)), $data, $content);
?>
```

Comment: Will there be more than 2 dimensions?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes it could be, I have solved with 2 but I need recursive call function

Comment: I have modified the question with another solution, stuck with it too.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it if someone needs that.

```
<?php
function flat_array(&$array){
    foreach($array as $key=>$val){
        if(is_array($val)){
            foreach($val as $k=>$v){
                $array["{$key}_$k"] = $v;
            }
            unset($array[$key]);
            flat_array($array);
            break;
        }
    }
}
$content = "hello {{var}} world {{var2}} of what {{var3_var5}}?";
$data = ["var"=>"hello", "var2"=>"world", "var3"=>["var4"=>"what","var5"=>"asdf","var6"=>["last"=>"world", "another"=>["wo"=>"asfasfd"]]]];
echo __FILE__.":".__LINE__.'<hr><pre>';print_r($data);echo'</pre>';
flat_array($data);
echo __FILE__.":".__LINE__.'<hr><pre>';print_r($data);echo'</pre>';
echo preg_replace(array_map(function ($k) {return "/\{\{$k}}/";}, array_keys($data)), $data, $content);
?>
```